# Symfony : CreateForm / Why my textarea do not appear?

Tags: css, forms, symfony, symfony4

I have a problem to display a textarea from a form I've created with Symfony.

The textarea appears in html but it has no `display: block` in the css. It has nothing in the css, to be clear.

When I add a `display:block` in the css myself, it simply stripped by chrome/firefox.

The problem only happens when I create the form from a separate Class, not when I create it in controller's function.

Here is my code:

AdController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\Ad;
use App\Form\AdType;
use App\Repository\AdRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class AdController extends AbstractController
{


    /**
     * Create ad
     *
     * @Route("/ads/new", name="ads_create")
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create(){

         $ad = new Ad();

         $form = $this->createForm(AdType::class, $ad);


        return $this->render('ad/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }


}
```

AdType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Ad;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class AdType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('slug')
            ->add('price')
            ->add('introduction')
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
                'attr' => array('cols' => '5', 'rows' => '5')])
            ->add('coverImage')
            ->add('rooms')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Ad::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Create ad{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>


        {{form_start(form)}}

            {{ form(form) }}



        {{form_end(form)}}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried a lot of things but I still don't understand how to solve this problem. Do someone have an idea about it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried row_attr? `->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
                'row_attr' => array('cols' => '5', 'rows' => '5')])`

Comment: Yes, I tried but it don't work. 

And it strange but my ->add('introduction') is also a textarea and it have no problem. I start to think it's not a problem with my code but a bug in Symfony ?!

Comment: In twig, try to use `{{ form(form) }}` and remove `{{form_start(form)}}` `{{form_end(form)}}` , see https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap4.html

Comment: I tried it, it do not change anything. And even if I delete AdType.php and created it again, the problem remain.

Comment: ->add('content', TextareaType::class, ['attr' => array('class'=>"form-control", 'cols' => '5', 'rows' => '5')]) ?

Comment: Still not work.

Even if I change TextType, It don't work. It's very strange.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem

**SOLUTION** was to disable AdBlock

Adblock hid the textarea beacause it thought it was an ad (your entities name begin with the "ad" prefix)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that `content` is some kind of reserved word.

What happens when you rename the property?

Additionally, try rendering the form widgets separately, such as :

```
{{ form_widget(form.title) }}
{{ form_widget(form.slug) }}
...
{{ form_widget(form.content) }} 
...
```

If that gives you any error - you will have some more information you can debug

Answer (score 0):

cache problem of your browser empty chrome cache or use private browser