# Symfony5 Interview Questions Form with CollectionType and Questions from Database

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am new to symfony and try to rewrite an existing software with it.

I have three entities, User (id, name, email, ...), Question (id, question, sortValue), Answer (id, user(id), question(id), answer).
So basically we have a Many-to-Many Relation with an attribute in the join table (Answer#answer).

An administrator can define add or remove interview questions in the database and the user sees all questions with a corresponding textarea field on an interview page. The user is not forced to answer all questions and only answered (non-empty) are not stored in the database. Furthermore the user has no answered questions in the beginning.

My current approach is a CollectionType with Answer as entry_type

edit.twig

```
/* [..] */
{{ form_row(form.answers) }}
/* [..] */
```

ProfileFormType.php

```
class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{

    /* [..] */

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answers', CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type'        => AnswerType::class,
                'label' =>  false,
            ]);
    }
    
    /* [..] */
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

AnswerType.php

```
class AnswerType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answer', TextareaType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Answer::class
        ));
    }
}
```

With this I only see textarea fields for the questions already answered and i don't really have an idea how to change that. I read that it is possible to use javascript to dynamically add fields, but i don't want the user to add the questions first (would lead to less complete interviews). Another idea would be to use Question as entry_type, but in that case i have no idea how i map the data back to the user Entity (user_id reference in answer).

Comment: Have you try any of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65738018/12042800) and still doesn't appear?

Comment: Befor you create the form: for every not yet answered question add an empty answer to the user's answers collection

Comment: @KostasKolovos: no, its not because of an adblocker (i have an exception for that site), but good to know that it could cause problems. I know that the unanswered questions do not appear because the actual Question-Entity is not referenced in the form yet. My problem is that I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: @ThomasBaumgartner I had the idea modify the getAnswers()-method of User so that it optionally uses a right join on answers and questions and returns that instead of the relation. But in that case I would need to access the database from within an entity class. I guess there is better way. I read about FormEvents, is this the way to go? And are there corresponding examples? I only found some that add/remove single fields to/from a form.

Comment: If you add one toString() in the Question entity with a text that will be used as a placeholder for your answers?